Dynamic File Selection for Frame Encoding in HM Encoder
I am currently working on a challenging task and would appreciate some guidance. I need to modify the source code of the HM encoder so that it can select a different file for each frame to be encoded. For example, frame 1 and frame 2 would be encoded from file 1, frame 3 from file 2, and so on. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to approach this?
Thank you!
I attempted to declare a function that prompts the user to specify an extension for the file. However, the issue is that the input file is parsed from the beginning, and the buffer is created based on that initial file.
